# How to clip connecting datasets to each other in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, administrative-boundaries

I have two datasets, one with administrative boundaries from one source, and coastlines from another source. I want to use both these sources to create a map, however the administrative boundaries are not the same as the coastline, meaning they overlap on certain areas. Is there anyway I can get these to connect to each other so that they're both following the exact same path? I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'Method' parameter to control how the overlap is dealt with, the 'Remove Overlap' tool in ArcGIS Pro would appear to do what you need.

Remove Overlaps - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/remove-overlap-multiple.htm#L_

It's also worth familiarising yourself with the Overlay Toolset - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/remove-overlap-multiple.htm#L_